# Set variable on failure and pipe the output anyway in a /bin/sh script

Tags: shell, sh

How can I set a variable (`FAILED=1`) when `some-command` fails, but still be able to process its output in `do-something-with-output-anyway`?

I’ve got this:

```
FAILED=0
tmp="$(mktemp)"
some-command >>"$tmp" || FAILED=1
cat "$tmp" | do-something-with-output-anyway
rm "$tmp"
```

But how to do it in one command? This won’t work:

```
FAILED=0
{ some-command || FAILED=1 ; } | do-something-with-output-anyway
```

… because `FAILED=1` is only set in the `{}` subshell (I think?).

Edit suggested by @fedorqui: i.e. something along the lines of:

```
sh -c 'echo bam ; exit 1' || FAILED=1 | sed 's/^/x/' && echo $FAILED
```

should output:

```
xbam
1
```

Comment: where's `cat "$tmp"` in your one liner?

Comment: @Jahid, that’s the point, there’s no `$tmp` file, just a direct pipe.

Comment: What about `some-command || FAILED=1 | do-something-with-output-anyway`

Comment: @Jahid, how about trying your suggestion before posting it?

Comment: @Jahid, `sh -c 'echo bam ; exit 1' || FAILED=1 | sed 's/^/x/' && echo $FAILED` should output
`xbam
1`

Comment: You could start by asking in a better way: explain what you are looking for, what are the steps you want to replicate, etc. The current script looks a bit obscure and your feedback in comments even worse.

Comment: @fedorqui, arguably, shell *is* obscure. Updated.

Comment: Shell can be obscure, but you need the ability to simplify things by explaining them in normal language. "How can I do this better? <piece of code>" is not the best way to ask questions here. "I want to execute a command and check if it ran properly; then, remove the file, etc, because my main goal here is to do Y" may be better.

Comment: @fedorqui, my main goal here is to “Set variable on failure and pipe the output anyway in a /bin/sh script” — or is it too cryptic perhaps? Hmm. Updated.

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is to catch `$?` after the command. If it is `0`, everything is fine; otherwise, something bad happened.

Comment: @fedorqui, could you prepare a code snippet with your solution and post it as an answer? I can’t get from your description it and I’ll be happy to accept.

Answer (score -1):

Exporting the variable before modifying it may solve your problem.

```
export FAILURE

{
    something || FAILURE=1
} | something-else
```

On a side note, instead of using `cat` to pipe its output, you could probably use `command < file`.

Comment: No way, see, if your solution worked, this: `export FAILURE=0 ; { sh -c 'echo abbaab ; exit 1' || FAILURE=1 } | tr a x ; echo $FAILURE` should output `xbbxxb` and then `1`. It outputs `0`.